# How to shorten code for Textbox controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I have 25 textbox controls. The following code is for 2 textboxes only. So for 25 textboxes the code is going to be long, can I shorten the code?

```
 Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles IDTextBox.KeyDown, DateDateTimePicker.KeyDown, ItemCodeTextBox.KeyDown, BrandTextBox.KeyDown, ItemTextBox.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And Me.IDTextBox.Focused Then
        Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focus()
    Else
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down And Me.IDTextBox.Focused Then
            Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focus()
        Else
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up And Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focused Then
                Me.IDTextBox.Focus()
            Else
                If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focused Then
                    Me.ItemCodeTextBox.Focus()
                Else
                    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down And Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focused Then
                        Me.ItemCodeTextBox.Focus()
                    Else
                        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up And Me.ItemCodeTextBox.Focused Then
                            Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focus()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this question would be better titled "How do I enable WinForms navigation using ENTER and arrow keys"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use can make your code clean using "Select Case" instead of 'If' condition.
This would be much cleaner. [see this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/611892.aspx/1)

@Farook...... Try this

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Select Case True
        Case (e.KeyCode = Keys.Down And Me.ActiveControl.GetType IsNot GetType(DateTimePicker))
                Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True) 'forwards
        Case (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And Not (Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) AndAlso DirectCast(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox).Multiline))
            Me.Text = Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True).ToString  'forwards
        Case (e.KeyCode = Keys.Up And Me.ActiveControl.GetType IsNot GetType(DateTimePicker))
            Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, False, True, True, True)  'backwards
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't work in this case, because the code is comparing the state of multiple variables.

Comment: Rahil, your code is short too! There is a problem. When I am on the multiline textbox and when I press the up arrow key, the cursor goes to the previous textbox. We have to deselect arrow keys for the multiline textbox.

Comment: Rahil it's done. I've added this line: Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, False, False, False, False). Thank you very much for your support & comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to enable navigation of your form with the enter and arrow keys.

If that is the case:

1. Delete that code
2. Select the design view of the form
3. Right click on the VB toolbar and make sure the "layout" toolbar is visible
4. Click on the button on the far right called "Tab Order"
5. Click on each control in the order that you want
6. Set the "KeyPreview" property of the form to TRUE

Then add the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
  If Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(DateTimePicker) Then
    'DateTimePicker
    Select Case e.KeyCode
      Case Keys.Enter
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True) 'forwards
    End Select
  ElseIf Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) AndAlso Not DirectCast(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox).Multiline Then
    'normal Textbox
    Select Case e.KeyCode
      Case Keys.Up
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, False, True, True, True)  'backwards
      Case Keys.Down, Keys.Enter
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True) 'forwards
    End Select
  ElseIf Me.ActiveControl.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) AndAlso DirectCast(Me.ActiveControl, TextBox).Multiline Then
    'multiline Textbox - ignore
  Else
    'all other controls
    Select Case e.KeyCode
      Case Keys.Up
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, False, True, True, True)  'backwards
      Case Keys.Down, Keys.Enter
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True) 'forwards
    End Select
  End If
End Sub
```

The up/down arrow keys are actually used by the DateTimePicker and so need to be excluded as navigation commands for it. Conversely, a multiline textbox uses the ENTER key and therefore ENTER must be excluded as a navigation command in that case.

Comment: SSS, your code is really short. The up/down arrow keys are actually used by the DateTimePicker and so need to be excluded as navigation controls for it is a good thought. Thanks alot

Comment: Hi Farook, I have updated the code to omit multiline textboxes completely. I also flipped the structure so that the top level choice is the type of control, and the inner part is how to handle each key. I hope this is easier for you to adapt so you can handle each control how you want to.